# React Redux Why most guideline separate every types?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm curious why most guidelines of separate every types?

for example:

```
 //List of Posts
FETCH_POSTS: 'fetch_posts',
FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS: 'fetch_posts_success',
FETCH_POSTS_ERROR: 'fetch_posts_failure',

// Single POST
FETCH_POST: 'fetch_post',
FETCH_POST_SUCCESS: 'fetch_post_success',
FETCH_POST_ERROR: 'fetch_post_failure',
```

I've got the idea within success and error got separated. But for `fetch_posts` and `fetch_post` that only has one job to trigger ex: `isLoading` why it must got separate? why not make one type for ex: `FETCHING`?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, it is not a requirement nor a guideline, in the [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) they actually mention that this is a developers choice, so, it is not like it should be separated, just it makes it more clear what is happening when you separate them in your reducer actions

Comment: @Icepickle thanks for commenting. yeah that makes more sense it will more clear what is happening in my reducers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer that actions is not what you want to do — it's what already happened (according to Dan Abramov). So there is no place to "*ing": `FETCH_POST` may be named as `FETCH_POST_REQUEST` (user just requested posts), and succedeed or failed then.

I asked the same question in the past and somewhere found the answer that this is only one of the implementations. It has its pros and cons, but in fact, the standard FSA contains an object with meta-data that may contain statuses (request / success / failure and maybe some more).

Some advantages of the solution with different action types:

- a simple switch in the reducer;
- a simple usage of `redux-saga` (`takeEvery('FETCH_POST')` is easier than takeEvery and filter by some props);
- it have clear names (for example, it's easier to debug in redux-devtools when you just looking at list of dispatched actions);

But another approach has advantages too:

- You can easily handle any async processes in a reducer for any action (if you're just looking for `action.meta.status`, for example). But it has a fairly narrow field of application, for example, a single progress bar for all asynchronous tasks.
- less action types;

I believe that both have a right to life, but you should clearly understand what benefits it will bring to your application, and which one will be easier to maintain.

Of course, nothing prevents you from mixing these approaches, but this may cause errors and difficulties in the support, so be careful.

Comment: If someone knows more advantages for any of this approaches: offer to edit or write them in the comments and I will add to this answer. Perhaps we can assemble here the complete comparison of these approaches, facilities, difficulties and pain they produce. Thanks!

Comment: if I using same action types, how I define the reducer? I mean like you said if different types I can easily use `switch` statement.

Comment: In the approach A (different action types) you can just switch by action.type and do something.

Comment: In the approach B you have to check that is action.type that you needed (for example, `if (action.type !== 'FETCH_POST') { return state; }` and then switch by action.meta.status).
But if you have the case from my example (single progress bar for all async actions) — you don't want to filter it by action.type and just switch by action.meta.status. (But don't forget to check for existence of this props).